# Why isn't translational energy quantized?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation, spectroscopy, molecules

I was reading over this article on spectroscopy/molecular energy levels: https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Spectroscopy/Molecular_energy_levels. It says that translational energy is not quantized. Is this always true, or is it only true for a free particle?

Comment: They will be quantized as well, but at extremely low temperatures.

Answer (score 6):

The potential energy is typically a function of the relative coordinates, v.g. $\vert x_1-x_2\vert$ (assuming 2 coordinates for simplicity).  Thus by going to the center of mass $X$ and relative coordinates $x$ [the Hamiltonian separates](http://physics.oregonstate.edu/~corinne/COURSES/ph426/notes2.pdf)
$$
H=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2(m_1+m_2)}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial X^2}
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + V(x)
$$
with $\mu$ the reduced mass, so that the solution to the center of mass (or translational) degree of freedom is just the free-particle solution
\begin{align}
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2(m_1+m_2)}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial X^2}\psi_{CM}(x)&=E_{CM}\psi_{CM}(x)\\
\psi_{CM}(X)&=e^{iPX/\hbar}\, ,\qquad \frac{\hbar^2 P^2}{2(m_1+m_2)}=E_{CM}
\end{align}
which, like a free particle, has no restriction on $E$ and is thus not quantized.

Answer (score 2):

The translational energy depends on the momentum, which is is a continuous parameter (as the Fourier transform of position, which is also continuous). For a particle restricted to live on a finite lattice or a box with periodic boundary conditions, the allowed momentum values will be quantized, but for a macroscopic system the allowed momenta will be incredibly close together and effectively continuous.

Comment: by that argument, why would energy ever be quantized?  It is a continuous parameter (as the Fourier transform of time, which is also continuous).

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Good question. The answer is that while there's a sense in which energy is the FT of time, it's not quite the same sense in which momentum is the FT of position. There's no time operator $T$ satisfying $[T, H] = i \hbar$ the way there is for position and momentum. If there were, then energy would indeed always be continuous.

Comment: I'm aware of this, which is why I think the FT argument is not so convincing as stated.  Possibly one needs to observe that for bound states the motion is periodic whereas for unbound motion is it not, but since classically there is in principle no restriction on the frequency of the motion this is still not complete.  The argument works better for $x$ and $p$ since bound states are (loosely) associated with standing wave.  Huge discussion of this in Born's textbook but no time to reread this.